# Failure to partition a dataframe to write to DeltaLake

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException` while attempting to write to Delta.

```
E               pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The provided partitioning does not match of the table.
E                - provided: identity(class_name)
E                - table:
```

This is what I am using:

```
                df.repartition(col('class_name')).write \
                    .option("mergeSchema","true") \
                    .format("delta") \
                    .mode("append") \
                    .partitionBy("class_name") \
                    .saveAsTable("dummy_table")
```

I've already tested the command without partitioning and it works fine but I need to partition the table by that column. The below works fine.

```
                df.write \
                    .option("mergeSchema","true") \
                    .format("delta") \
                    .mode("append") \
                    .saveAsTable("dummy_table")
```

In truth, the column is created before using .withColumn but I'm assuming that shouldn't be a problem as the write to Delta works fine.

Based on the page from Delta it should work.

https://delta.io/blog/2023-01-18-add-remove-partition-delta-lake/

Comment: I will check if the version is the latest, or that where is said this feature is implemented

Comment: delta-spark 2.3 is what I have.

Comment: Your error is a Spark one, not a delta one. Can you please share all of your code, or a minimal reproducible example? You say that the column is created before using `.withColumn`, but the error seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: If initially the table was written without `partitionBy` then subsequent writes with `partitionBy` to the same table will fail because of incompatible partitioning.

Comment: You're right, it seems to be the case. I found an alternative which involves creating the partition when creating DeltaTable which appears to be the answer to my problem.